# Tensorflow built-in function passed as a variable doesn't work. How can I make it work?

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow

When I ran the below code,

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

class Config:
    activation = tf.nn.tanh

class Sample:

    def function(self, x):
        return self.config.activation(x)

    def __init__(self, config):
        self.config = config

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with tf.Graph().as_default():
        config = Config()
        sample = Sample(config)
        with tf.Session() as sess:
            a = tf.constant(2.0)
            print sess.run(sample.function(a))
```

I get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 27, in <module>
    print sess.run(sample.function(a))
  File "test.py", line 11, in function
    return self.config.activation(x)
  File "/Users/byungwookang/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py", line 2019, in tanh
    with ops.name_scope(name, "Tanh", [x]) as name:
  File "/Users/byungwookang/anaconda/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 17, in __enter__
    return self.gen.next()
  File "/Users/byungwookang/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 4185, in name_scope
    with g.as_default(), g.name_scope(n) as scope:
  File "/Users/byungwookang/anaconda/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 17, in __enter__
    return self.gen.next()
  File "/Users/byungwookang/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2839, in name_scope
    if name:
  File "/Users/byungwookang/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 541, in __nonzero__
    raise TypeError("Using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed. "
TypeError: Using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed. Use `if t is not None:` instead of `if t:` to test if a tensor is defined, and use TensorFlow ops such as tf.cond to execute subgraphs conditioned on the value of a tensor.
```

In contrast, this code works as expected.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

class Config:
    activation = np.tanh

class Sample:

    def function(self, x):
        return self.config.activation(x)

    def __init__(self, config):
        self.config = config

if __name__ == "__main__":
    config = Config()
    sample = Sample(config)
    print sample.function(2.0)
    print np.tanh(2.0)
```

It gives

```
0.964027580076
0.964027580076
```

I am curious why one can't pass a tensorflow built-in function as a variable (as done in the first code above), and whether there is a way to avoid the above error. Especially given the second code where a numpy function is passed nicely as a variable, it seems very strange to me that tensorflow doesn't allow this.

Comment: This is very curious!

Answer (score 0):

The reason your stuff does not work is because in your case

```
print sample.function # <bound method Sample.function of <__main__.Sample instance at 0xXXX>>
print tf.nn.tanh      # <function tanh at 0xXXX>
```

are not the same, whereas in your second case they match. So when you run `sample.function(a)`, not tanh but something else is executed.

---

It is hard for me to understand the purpose of all these classes and functions to do a simple job, so I just found the easiest way to modify whatever was written for it to work:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

def config():
    return {'activation': tf.nn.tanh}

class Sample:
    def function(self, x):
        return self.config['activation'](x)

    def __init__(self, config):
        self.config = config

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with tf.Graph().as_default():  # this is also not needed
        sample = Sample(config())
        with tf.Session() as sess:
            a = tf.constant(2.0)
            print sess.run(sample.function(a))
```

Comment: It's still strange that the code doesn't work in tensorflow but does work in numpy.

Comment: @Salvardor Dali thanks a lot for suggesting a solution. My codes above were intended as a toy code to explain the problem I faced in a much larger code. While your suggested code certainly works, I am curious if there is a way to make my tensorflow code work in a way that's more similar to my numpy code. Also, it's hard for me to understand why I got such an error message.